# Spring Rest API and AngularJs Project structure

Tags: angularjs, spring

Im new to putting Spring and Angular together and would like to check if there is a preferred project structure to incorporate both of these together in the SAME project. 
My current test structure is like this

[image]

This is all done through spring Boot so the Application has

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(rest.class,args);
}

}
```

it means i can go to my index when i run the application by just going to :8080

**QUESTION**

Is there a problem with this structure?

Should i be using a different structure?

Comment: The fact that your server is using Spring does not influence how you structure your js code. For the structure of your js code there are different ways, it is an opinion based thing and likely off-topic on SO. I recommend to google "angular js project structure" to read some (opinionated) articles on the topic

Answer (score 1):

As LionC mentions, a lot is just opinion based when it comes to directory structure.

AngularJS's powerful RESTful functionality provides a great way to leverage a robust Spring server side, but managing the separation of these layers is a fairly difficult job in comparison to your classic Spring MVC and too big to discuss here.

Take a look at [JHipster](http://jhipster.github.io/) for a neat solution, using Yeoman to unify the two.  You can find a pre-generated sample at https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app